# Weglot translate two times my text, an idea?

Tags: shopify, translation, translate

i'm using the plugin Weglot for translate my website on Shopify but I don't understand why but sometimes the plugin wants to translate a text two times.
[the first and third text are the sime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf9EM.jpg)

If someone have an idea, i'm here.

Thank's for helping.

Comment: Reach out the app developers.

Comment: Hi, try to contact them on their support, which is support@weglot.com